# Can't create archive file after update to Xcode Version 7.0

Tags: xcode7

I just update to  Xcode Version 7.0 and suddenly the option **archive** appears as disabled !  and I can't create the ipa file

[image]

Comment: You can't archive selecting a simulator as a target device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deselect iOS Simulator from your target when you want to create the archive.

Select Generic iOS Device or your connected device and the Archive button will be selectable again.